# What is the correct way to put an image from the internet in answers?

Tags: discussion, images

I like to put images from google search into my answers when I am answering a question. I usually just go to the site, get the URL to that image, and paste it to Stackexchange "Insert Image", which converts it to an imgur link.

Usually I just leave it at that, but [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/94998/34288) makes me think about whether my approach is correct.

**Should we give attribution below the image we get from the internet?**

How does imgur handle those images? Do they have an internal attribution table to track images uploaded to Stackexchange sites?

Comment: One should _always_ give credit to the author of a work you use for your own purposes. Don't know how to answer the rest of it, so just leaving this part as a comment.

Comment: You should always mention where you got information. It doesn't matter whether you are citing a Wikipedia article or copying an image. Attribution is important, because it is the original work of someone else. Always try to show this in your posts. Of course you can format the links to make them easier to read than those that Will puts up.

Answer (score 4):

> Should we give attribution below the image we get from the internet?

Preferably yes. Sometimes people forget, but if nothing else, its the nice thing to do.

> Do they have internal attribution table to track images uploaded to Stackexchange sites?

No.

As for how to attribute - I favour the method mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301054/135565), which I reproduce below

> Its worth remembering *why* we encourage the use of imgur - if wikimedia changes their links or OP removes the image your image is broken. In future, if SE chooses to move off imgur, it also simplifies the process of fixing links. There's *many* advantages to using imgur, and space is relatively cheap.
>
> You can *totally* link an off site image - just use the hyperlink option, and add a ! in front like so
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>(Example Image taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Philae_Temple_R03.jpg) - Aswan (Egypt): Philae Temple taken by Marc Ryckaert (MJJR))</sub>
>
> That said, chances are, for the reasons I mentioned above, someone will edit it to use imgur anyway, and we really do prefer people use imgur (and maybe link back to the original/attribute as needed - I've used sub tags here)

Comment: If you are referencing an image without uploading it to the Stack Exchange Imgur, remember that the same caveats as with other off-site links apply: **the image may be removed or changed** by whoever is hosting it, and your answer must make sense without it or even with a completely different image in its place. This was illustrated with the switch of Stack Exchange to HTTPS, as quite a few off-site images were served over HTTP (even when they were available over HTTPS) and browsers will typically refuse to embed HTTP content into a page served over HTTPS. The result was images "disappearing".

Answer (score 1):

While @JourneymanGeek's answer is a good one, it is important to note that you can find all the info you need [in the help section on referencing:](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

> ### How to reference material written by others
>
> [Plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - posting the work of others with no indication that it is
>   not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your
>   answer being down-voted or deleted.
>
> When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question (from
>   another site or in an answer on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange) make
>   sure you do all of the following:
>
> - Provide a [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) to the original page or answer
> - [Quote](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author Example:
>
> > According to [Ernest Hemingway - Biographical on Nobelprize.org](https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1954/hemingway-bio.html),
> >     Hemingway saw combat when he was a teenager. It says:
> >
> > > After the United States entered the First World War, he joined a
> > >       volunteer ambulance unit in the Italian army. Serving at the front, he
> > >       was wounded, was decorated by the Italian Government, and spent
> > >       considerable time in hospitals ....
> >
> > *[other sources, quotes, explanations, etc. necessary to complete the answer]*
>
> Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas
>   to support your own. And *always* give proper credit to the author and
>   site where you found the text, **including a direct link to it**.
>
> See also:
>
> - [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)
> - [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)
> - [How do I write a good answer?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

---

This is the most official stance of Stackexchange on the topic of referencing material I could find.

Also note that I failed to follow its very guidance by copy-pasting all the information from the link - but I think I can be forgiven under these circumstances.